# Not seeing any cookies after request on Roku

Tags: cookies, roku, brightscript

I have a Roku app that will be making several asynchronous calls to back-end services while a video plays. It's ***possible*** that some of these calls may take place at the same time. These calls all depend on cookies for authentication.

Because the calls depend on cookies for authentication, I need to utilize a single `roUrlTransfer` object. If I create a new `roUrlTransfer` instance for every request, they won't share a cookie cache

Because two calls may happen simultaneously, though, I cannot use a single `roUrlTransfer` object. Per the [Roku documentation](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifurltransfer.md):

> Each roUrlTransfer object can perform only one asynchronous operation at one time. After starting an asynchronous operation, you cannot perform any other data transfer operations using that object until the asynchronous operation has completed, as indicated by receiving an roUrlEvent message whose GetSourceIdentity value matches the GetIdentity value of the roUrlTransfer.

To work around these two issues, I created a wrapper object. I maintain one singleton `roUrlTransfer` object called "cookieJar" and then I spin up a new `roUrlTransfer` instance per request:

```
' ********************************************************************
' ** URL class to streamline adding query parameters and making requests.
' ********************************************************************

Function Downloader() As Object
   return {
      Send: Downloader_Send
      AsyncWait: Downloader_AsyncWait
   }
End Function

Function CookieJar() As Object
   if m.cookiejar = invalid
      m.cookiejar = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
      m.cookiejar.EnableCookies()
   end if
   return m.cookiejar
End Function

Function Downloader_Send(req={} As Object)
   if req.url <> invalid
      m.req = req

      m.http = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
      m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
      m.http.SetPort(m.port)
      m.http.EnableEncodings(true)

      ' ParseURL is a helper function I wrote that just breaks a URL into
      ' its components: scheme, host, path, query, and fragment
      m.url = ParseURL(req.url)
      m.http.EnableCookies()
      m.http.AddCookies(CookieJar().GetCookies(m.url.host, m.url.path))

      m.http.SetUrl(req.url)

      if req.method <> invalid
         m.http.SetRequest(req.method)
      else
         m.http.SetRequest("GET")
      end if

      if req.timeout <> invalid
         m.timeout = req.timeout
      else
         m.timeout = 5000
      end if

      data = {}

      if req.body <> invalid
         if m.http.AsyncPostFromString(FormatJSON(req.body))
            data = m.AsyncWait()
         end if
      else
         if m.http.AsyncGetToString()
            data = m.AsyncWait()
         end if
      end if

   end if

   return data
End Function

Function Downloader_AsyncWait() As Dynamic
   event = wait(m.timeout, m.port)
   if type(event) = "roUrlEvent"
      print "Headers:"
      print event.GetResponseHeaders()
      print "Adding cookies to cookie jar:"
      print m.http.GetCookies(m.url.host, m.url.path)
      print m.http.GetCookies("", "/")
      CookieJar().AddCookies(m.http.GetCookies(m.url.host, m.url.path))
      return {
         statusCode: event.GetResponseCode()
         error: event.getFailureReason()
         body: event.GetString()
         headers: event.GetResponseHeaders()
      }
   else if event = invalid
      m.http.AsyncCancel()
   end if
   return invalid
End Function
```

For the sake of testing my code, I spun up a very simple ExpressJS server which does nothing but set a cookie:

```
var express = require("express");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.cookie("key", "value", {
        domain: "192.168.1.102:3333",
        path: "/",
        expire: Date.now() + 3600000
    });
    res.send("Done");
});

var server = app.listen(3333, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Then within my Roku app (on the main screen) I have the following:

```
httpClient = Downloader()

httpClient.Send({
    ' My local IP address
    url: "http://192.168.1.102:3333"
})
```

When I run this on my Roku, I see the following in the debug log:

```
Headers:
<Component: roAssociativeArray> =
{
    connection: "keep-alive"
    content-length: "13"
    content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    date: "Tue, 11 Aug 2020 17:29:52 GMT"
    etag: "W/"d-w+Ote5otCKx40dtR446Vz7wX66U""
    set-cookie: "key=value; Path=/"
    x-powered-by: "Express"
}
Adding cookies to cookie jar:
<Component: roArray> =
[
]
<Component: roArray> =
[
]
```

Neither `m.http.GetCookies(m.url.host, m.url.path)` nor `m.http.GetCookies("", "/")` returned any cookies. But you can clearly see the cookie in the header! So why can't I access it?

As a note, `m.url.host` is `192.168.1.102:3333` and `m.url.path` is   (blank), in case that helps with making sense of anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for a full day I figured out that Roku doesn't handle ***ports*** in cookie domains properly. When a cookie is served by `192.168.1.102:3333` Roku internally marks the cookie as belonging to `192.168.1.102` (no port).

This has two implications:

1. If a cookie is served with the `...; domain=...;` attribute, and this domain contains a port, Roku utterly fails to parse the `set-cookie` header and no cookie is extracted
2. If a cookie is served **without** this attribute then Roku will parse the `set-cookie` header, however `GetCookies()` will only return the cookie if given no domain (`""`) or given the port-less domain. `GetCookies("192.168.1.102", "/")` returns the cookie but `GetCookies("192.168.1.102:3333", "/")` does not

Because the purpose of my code is to share cookies between multiple roUrlTransfer instances, using `GetCookies("", "/")` to get **all** cookies was acceptable, so we'll be modifying our back-end to remove the `...; domain=...;` attribute from our `set-cookie` headers